# IE8 Not picking up 'Float Left' and 'Fonts'

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, fonts, cross-browser, css-float

Hey my site is working fine except in IE8. The Menu bar is not displayed properly. My theory is the Float Left is not working but it could be something else. Also the font which is Calibri isn't showing up properly. Is there any way to fix these two problems. The website is [eagleview.it](http://eagleview.it)

This is the nav ul for index.css:

```
nav ul {
width:900px;
list-style: none; 
margin:15px;
position: relative;
}
nav ul li { display::inline;}
nav ul li a {
float:left;
display: block;
padding: 0 15px;
margin: 10px 12px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:600;
font-size:15px;
opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: { display::inline;}  should be { display:inline;}

Comment: also, i cant right click inspect element on your site...no clue why, but you should look into that. i'm on win7 chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ie8 doesn't recognise "nav" as an element.

Simplest option is to change to a div, or check modernizr out.

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul class="group">
            <li style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif"><a href="about.html" style="text-decoration:none">About</a></li>
            <li style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif"><a href="services.html" style="text-decoration:none">Services</a></li>
        <li style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif"><a href="testimonials.html" style="text-decoration:none">Testimonials</a></li>
           <li style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif"><a href="eagleview.html" style="text-decoration:none">Eagleview</a></li>
            <li style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif"><a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration:none">Contact</a></li>
          <li style="font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif"><a href="consulting.html" style="text-decoration:none">Consulting</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

With css of

```
#nal ul li {}
#nav ul li a {}
```

etc

Comment: simpler option is html5shiv.js

Comment: @Robbie ok I changed it and its now messed up in firefox as well..Check it and the source

Comment: @Robbie my mistake it works! THANK YOU SO MUCH. Any ideas on the font cross browser?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "font cross browser"? If you want to know how to get embeded fonts into different browsers: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator