# IE8 float problems arise again

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, css-float

## Context

In my header, I want to place my little login menu "LOGIN" and "Help" to the right of the page at the same height as the logo (red rectangle) on the left.

## Problem

The layout is not working on IE8.

It works as intended on Chrome :

[image]

But it gives this on IE8 :

[image]

or this :

[image]

## Code

#### HTML

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="Login">
        <a id="LB_GotoLogin" tabindex="30" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$LB_GotoLogin','')">LOGIN</a>
        <br><br>
        <a id="LB_Help" tabindex="30" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$LB_Help','')">Help</a>
    </div>
    <a href="/Default.aspx" style="text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1;">
        <img src="Logo.jpg" style="height:64px;border: 0;">
    </a>
</header>
```

#### CSS

```css
.header
{
    padding: 18px 50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: normal;
    height: 64px;
}

.login
{
    float: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    width: 100px;
}
```

## What I tried

1. I tried placing the floated-right element (login) **before** the logo, it gave the first IE8 image I included instead of the second. (As stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811029/divs-wont-float-in-ie8))
2. I placed a width to the floated element as stated at multiple places.
3. Every container are `<div>`s. As stated [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441951/ie8-not-picking-up-float-left-and-fonts), IE8 doesn't recognise other tags.
4. Tried making everything `inline-blocks` with the IE8 hack (`*dispay: inline; *zoom: 1;)

Nothing worked.

## Question

How can I make my layout to work for IE8? (What have I missed?)

Comment: Class `login` and class `Login` are two different classes. Some browsers may be tolerant of this (but they shouldn't be), IE8 is not.

Comment: @Sifu Margin 0px auto doesn't work in IE8, which is dumb. Usually what I do is do percent width and margin for IE8. If you have an 80% with then you have a margin left and right of 10% each. Let me know if that helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Thanks for the heads up, margins are also broken for IE8 but I can't afford having percentage margins for smaller screens. NiettheDarkAbsol found my problem (case sensitive classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Niet the Dark Absol* noted,

> Class "login" and class "Login" are two different classes. Some browsers may be tolerant of this (but they shouldn't be), IE8 is not.

Internet Explorer 8 is case sensitive, while the other browsers are not.

Having the same exact class names fixed the problem.